# Why we should put JavaScript code inside an IIFE?

Tags: javascript

I have recently started the Angular.js tutorial which shows code written inside of an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). I was wondering why should we put our JavaScript inside such a construct? Is it because of security reasons?

Eg: Why this:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("AppName", [])
})();
```

And not just this:

```
var app = angular.module("AppName", [])
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that IIFE was another way of calling it. I'll vote to close the question.

Comment: It's all good, I just wanted to clarify terms, and the other chap noticed that with the clarified terms this had already been asked.  A closure is really something different than an IFFE, though IIFE's are a way to create a closure.

Comment: Notice, that the examples are doing totally different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having app as a global variable could cause conflicts

Answer (score 1):

It prevents you from creating a global variable.

Comment: But then I guess it would be useless if I use require.js right?

Comment: pretty much, because requirejs will wrap it in a closure of its own.